# Get custom taxonomy name for custom taxonomy template

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy with slug news_custom, and it has some terms.
I want to create a custom taxonomy template. I called it taxonomy-news_custom.php and I want to get a name of term of taxonomy. Example:

www.test.com/news_custom/cars

www.test.com/news_custom/animals

and in my template get as title cars o animals etc.

this is code

```
$name = get_term( get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ), 'news_custom' ); 
 <h2>NAME CATEGORY IS: <?php echo $name->name;  ?></h2>
```

But don't work! Why?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this helps, because maybe something else is missing or wrong. By not working what do you mean? Is wordpress resolving another template other than your taxonomy-nes_custom.php? If the page prints 'NAME CATEGORY IS: [[empty]]' that's a good sign.

But for starters, try: `$queried_category = get_queried_object();` and then `<h2>NAME CATEGORY IS: <?php echo $queried_category->term_name; ?></h2>` or `$queried_category->name`